# rsync --sparse does transfer whole data

Tags: rsync, sparse-matrix

I have some VM Images that need to synced everyday. The VM files are sparse'd.

To save network traffic i only want to transfer the real datas of the images. 
I try it with --sparse option at rsync but on network traffic i see that the whole size get transfered over network and not only the real data usage.

If i use rsync -zv --sparse then only the real size get transmitted over network and everything is ok. But i dont want to compression the file because of the cpu usage.

Shouldnt the --sparse option transfer only real datas and the "null datas" get created locally to save network traffic?

Is there a workaround without compression?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look a [this discussion](https://serverfault.com/questions/66338), specifically, [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/435514).

It seems that the solution is to do a `rsync --sparse` followed by a `rsync --inplace`.

On the first, `--sparse`, call, also use `--ignore-existing` to prevent already transferred sparse files to be overwritten, and `-z` to save network resources.

The second call, `--inplace`, should <s>update only modified chunks</s>. Here, compression is optional.

Also see [this post](http://gergap.wordpress.com/2013/08/10/rsync-and-sparse-files/).

**Update**

I believe the suggestions above won't solve your problem. I also believe that `rsync` is not the right tool for the task. You should search for other tools which will give you a good balance between network and disk I/O efficiency.

`Rsync` was designed for efficient usage of a single resource, the network. It assumes reading and writing to the network is much more expensive than reading and writing the source and destination files.

> We assume that the two machines are connected by a low-bandwidth high-latency bi-directional communications link. [The rsync algorithm, abstract](http://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/tech_report.html).

The algorithm, summarized in four steps.

1. The receiving side **β** sends checksums of blocks of size **S** of the destination file **B**.
2. The sending side **α** identify blocks that match in the source file **A**, at any offset.
3. **α** sends **β** a list of instructions made of either verbatim, non-matching, data, or matching block references.
4. **β** reconstructs the whole file from those instructions.

Notice that `rsync` normally reconstructs the file **B** as a temporary file **T**, then replaces **B** with **T**. In this case it must write the whole file.

The `--inplace` does not relieve `rsync` from writing blocks matched by **α**, as one could imagine. They can match at different offsets. Scanning **B** a second time to take new data checksums is prohibitive in terms of performance. A block that matches in the same offset it was read on step one could be skipped, but `rsync` does not do that. In the case of a sparse file, a null block of **B** would match for every null block of **A**, and would have to be rewritten.

The `--inplace` just causes `rsync` to write directly to **B**, instead of **T**. It will rewrite the whole file.

Comment: I already use --sparse and --inpace. The local server writes the whole file again, but just some mb got changed. Please see my output:

`lok/1.qcow2
      34.37G 100%   53.89MB/s    0:10:08 (xfer#1, to-check=3/9)
lik/1.qcow2
      34.37G 100%   40.15MB/s    0:13:36 (xfer#2, to-check=2/9)

sent 4.20M bytes  received 90.71M bytes  51.17K bytes/sec
total size is 139.13G  speedup is 1466.03`

Only 90MB changed, but the whole file got rewritten. Which uses a lot of CPU and IO. Isnt it possible that rsync dont rewrite the file and just replace the changes?

Comment: @user but are you performing two consecutive `rsync` invocations, or are you using `--sparse` and `--inplace` simultaneously in a single invocation?

Comment: If the file doesnt exist i make rsync --sparse, if the file exist i make rsync --inplace. This should be correct. The output from above was from rsync --inplace (the files are already existing on the backup server).

Comment: Yep, thats the idea. :P

Comment: Did you already used rsync with inplace / sparse successful? Could you show me your syntax?

Comment: @user I have experience with rsync, but I work mostly with small files. This answer is based on research I did, not on pratical use of inplace / sparse, sorry. Is it not working? Maybe you could show me your syntax and I would try to advice you further.

Comment: It is working. But the problem is that rsync rewrite the complete file. But over network it transfers only the new bits (as in example about, 70GB written, 90MB changes trasmitted). I think its not normal that the whole file get rewritten it should only replace changes. Rewrite the whole file makes high IO, takes much CPU and time.
My command (the file exist already on my backup server): `rsync -rvh --progress  --inplace root@1.1.1.1:/kvm /backup/kvm`

It get transfered correctly:
 `12G -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  33G Nov 15 13:06 vm-100-disk-1.qcow2`

Comment: @user please see my revised answer.

Answer (score 7):

The latest version of rsync can handle --sparse and --inplace together! I found the following github entry from 2016: https://github.com/tuna/rsync/commit/f3873b3d88b61167b106e7b9227a20147f8f6197

Comment: Does this mean that if a new sparse file shows up it will automatically create it as sparse, but when syncing changes on the next run it will in place and keep it sparse?

Comment: I have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to change the compression level to the lowest value (use the option `--compress-level=1`). The lowest compression level seems to be enough to reduce the traffic for sparse files. But I don't know, how the CPU usage is affected.